# Debug a client Socket not connecting, Autocad and ZWcad .NET Plugin

Tags: c#

We developed an Autocad plugin in C# with .NET that I want to port to ZWcad.

In theory the use almost the same api so only the namespaces and some references should be modified.

However, there is a bug where the client socket wouldn't connect to the sever with ZWcad only.

What I would like to know is how can I track the socket and know if there is something blocking it (i.e a firewall)

Comment: If you try to connect to a socket already in use, you will get an exception. Without knowing what classes you use, we can only guess. Please show the relevant code, where the connection is opened to the server.

Comment: Firewalls block by port number.  So it is always best to use a port number greater than 1000 that isn't being used by another application.  First step is to use PING to make sure that you can connect to server which doesn't use a port number.  Do you get a response like 200 OK or a 400/500 error?  Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?  Most server require HTTPS (uses TLS for encryption) and you will not get a response if TLS fails.  If you know how to use a sniffer check if http or https is being used.  See if there are any TLS packters.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments,  I was just missing the TLS12
so I just added those 2 line and it worked 
`ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`